# What's the difference between には及ばない and までもない？

Tags: grammar

Both までもない and には及ばない bear the meaning of "there is no need to do something". I know that には及ばない can also means "not reaching a certain level", but besides this case their meaning really seems to be really similar. Can somebody help me to understand the difference in usage? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Just from my own experience,

[までもない〕can be roughly translated to **inessential** or **不必要**.

> 1. そのことについてなら、いまさら話し合う**までもない**

It can be used this way to show that there is **no necessity** to talk about an already known fact or an event already deemed fix.

[ には及ばない] Can be used 2 ways.

1. As a **comparison** between two subjects A and B.

   > 数学で言えば、私(A)は彼(B)に**及ばない**.
2. Can also stand for **inessentiality** but more specifically, **rejection** against another person's idea or intent.

   > 帰り道は分かっていますので、心配には**及びません**.